# How to pass the selected object in a List to a second view when a button in a row is tapped

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following code, I have a list that has a button in each row. What I want is to be able to pass the selected `Fruit` from the `ContentView` to the `SecondView` when the button is tapped. Right now I can present the `SecondView` but it's blank, it has no text in it, in other words, I don't see the text, `Second View: [fruit name]`. Please note that I cannot use the `NavigationLink(destination:)` because I'm already using it to go to a details view when the rows are tapped.

How can I pass the selected fruit to the `Second View` when the button on each row is tapped?

### Fruit Object

```
struct Fruit: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
}
```

### Content View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var secondViewIsPresented = false
    
    var fruits = [Fruit(name: "Apple"), Fruit(name: "Orange")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(fruits){ fruit in
                HStack{
                    Text(fruit.name)
                    
                    Button("Tap Me"){
                        secondViewIsPresented.toggle()
                        SecondView(selectedFruit: fruit)
                    }
                    .frame(width:150, height: 35)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .buttonStyle(BlueButton())
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $secondViewIsPresented){
            // Here I cannot access the selected fruit
        }
    }
}

// style to make the button in the row work properly
// I'm showing it just for reference.
struct BlueButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 2 : 1)
    }
}
```

### Second View

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var selectedFruit: Fruit
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View: \(selectedFruit.name)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declaring `SecondView` inside the button's action closure has no effect. All this does is create a `SecondView`, then throw it away.

```
Button("Tap Me"){
    secondViewIsPresented.toggle()
    SecondView(selectedFruit: fruit) /// nope!
}
```

You want to present the selected fruit inside a sheet, right? But as you said, the problem is that you can't access the selected fruit from within the sheet.

That's where [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) comes in. This alternate version of sheet gets triggered when the `item` is not nil. You're then able to access the selected item inside its `content` closure.

```
struct ContentView: View {
//    @State private var secondViewIsPresented = false // delete this line
    @State private var selectedFruit: Fruit? /// replace with this
    
    var fruits = [Fruit(name: "Apple"), Fruit(name: "Orange")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(fruits){ fruit in
                HStack{
                    Text(fruit.name)
                    
                    Button("Tap Me"){
                        selectedFruit = fruit /// set the fruit
                    }
                    .frame(width:150, height: 35)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .buttonStyle(BlueButton())
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedFruit) { fruit in /// access selected fruit inside content closure
            SecondView(selectedFruit: fruit)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Sheet gets presented with correct item]

Comment: I never thought a dedicated function to pass an item as a data source existed, that's awesome.

Comment: If we use fullScreenCover so how to dismiss sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use EnvironmentObject for this.

Fruit struct remains same as before.

```
struct Fruit: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var name:String
}
```

You create an ObservableObject which is passed to FirstView during initialization.

```
class DataState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fruit: Fruit? = nil
}
```

Now the first view becomes

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var secondViewIsPresented = false
    //This has been added
    @EnvironmentObject var dataState: DataState
    var fruits = [
        Fruit(name: "Apple"),
        Fruit(name: "Orange")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(fruits){ fruit in
                HStack{
                    Text(fruit.name)
                    
                    Button("Tap Me"){
                        secondViewIsPresented.toggle()
                        //This has been changed
                        dataState.fruit = fruit
                        SecondView()
                    }
                    .frame(width:150, height: 35)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .buttonStyle(BlueButton())
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $secondViewIsPresented){
            // Here I cannot access the selected fruit
        }
    }
}

// style to make the button in the row work properly
// I'm showing it just for reference.
struct BlueButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 2 : 1)
    }
}
```

Also, you now access the passed object using EnvironmentObject

```
struct SecondView: View {
    //This has been added
    @EnvironmentObject var dataState: DataState

    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View: \(dataState.fruit?.name ?? "")")
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to make sure that you are passing in the DataState during the initialization of the FirstView

```
var appState = DataState()
FirstView()
    .environmentObject(self.appState))
```

Comment: But you're still not passing in anything to the `sheet`... how will `SecondView` be presented? Also note that sheets sometimes pre-render their contents, so even when you change `dataState` the updates might not be rendered.